# Google+ Api deprecated, solution for laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, google-signin, laravel-socialite, google-plus-signin

I have implemented login with google using socialite in laravel 5.1. Google plus apis are being deprecated, socialite resolved this for version 3.0 and above which is not supported by laravel 5.1. Any hacks around it?

Comment: its time for an upgrade

Answer (score 1):

Google plus apis will turn off on 7 March, 2019. Instead of google+ api you may use google api. Alternatively you can use **google sign-in** api.

You can check the documentation from [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in).

As far as I can tell, socialite doesn't yet support google api. So you may need to research a bit to integrate with the new API.